# getting docker container to never shutdown

Tags: docker

I'm trying to get a docker container to never shutdown.
If I run a docker container with the `-d` flag the container will be run in the background.

For example, can this be done:

> 1. Start docker container with `-it` flags
> 2. start entrypoint application
> 3. entrypoint application creates 10 other services/processes to run in that same container
> 4. entrypoint application terminates

Will the docker container stay up now that the application mentioned in the entrypoint has exited?

Comment: @BMW Isn't swarm used for docker instances? So if instance crashes you connect to another one in the swarm; in my case I care if the docker container crashes. I'm not sure how swarm is applicable to my situation. Could you elaborate a bit more? I'm interested!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply try? AFAIU `-d` or `-it` won't affect the container termination. And I guess you understand that starting those 10 processes means you violate the docker's idea of one process per container. Why don't you start 10 containers instead? You can also do that from your start container, and they will keep running even if the starting container will terminate.

You could also give docker docs a try: https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/

Comment: I'm currently trying, but it's easier said that done in my situation. Also I don't have a reason for why spawning 10 processes... I was given this scenario to look at. Do you know some way to force the container running even if the application running inside it terminates?

Comment: I've suggested a similar thing using `--restart` from http://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart Though I'm not sure if I start container with `-d` it still needs this restart policy

Comment: Your process might stop for whatever reason. Crashed, for example. Then you want the restart policy.

Answer (score 1):

`-it` flag means you want your standard input and output routed to/from container. This is basically and conceptually incompatible with running forever.

In general container will shutdown when entry point exits. if you want to keep container running you should run one (probably the last application) not as a background daemon but in foreground. for example if nginx is the last service you want to run. What you would do as your last line of entry point script (if thats a shell script) should be some thing like this:

```
nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Comment: What does the `-g` flag do inside a container? Is this flag specific to nginx or can I do `java myJavaApp -g "daemon off;"`

Comment: thats a flag for nginx, it has noting to do with docker and container. if your java app just runs in foreground thats enough and you can run it as `java myJavaApp`.

Comment: if your app exits, then you have to change your app so that instead of exiting, enters a loop and waits for what ever input it is expecting. thats how a proper app should act in a docker container